# Firestore functions won't trigger on event

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cli

Firestore Cloud Functions wont trigger on event, My function wont trigger onCreate, onUpdate, onDelete or onWrite. The JS script gets pushed to firestore sucsessfully.

Database desing:

```
-|search
    -|searchId
        -|id: string
        -|name: sting
        -|img: string
```

Rule:

```
match /search/{searchId}{
    allow read;
    allow write: if request.auth != null;
}


const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.updateIndex = functions.database.ref('/search/{searchId}').onWrite(event => {
    console.log('Working')
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using firestore, then the above won't work. The function that you have in the question is for firebase not firestore, change it to this:

```
exports.updateIndex = functions.firestore.document('search/{searchId}').onWrite(event => {
console.log('Working');
});
```

more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events